# Container with less opacity than childs

Tags: css

I want to make my webpage with a `background-color` with `opacity: 0.5` but the content inside the webpage will have an `opacity: 1`, as the default value.

The problem is that if I set `opacity: 0.5` to the container, all the childs inside this container gets the same `opacity` value.

I have searched about [opacity specifications](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity) and saw this:

> **Inherited**  No

but in my case it is being inherited so I have searched a bit more and found another [transparency specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) in which I saw this:

> If the object is a container element, then the effect is as if the contents of the container element were blended against the current background using a mask where the value of each pixel of the mask is .

So, as it seems that it is impossible to set a parent with less opacity than its childs, is there some workaround to get it?

<sub>**Note:** I think that in this case is not very important to add code (because you can reproduce it easily) but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bewoLaub/) I have created a simple JSFiddle "to play" with it.</sub>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

If you only want a semi-transparent background without affecting contents, you can use a [`rgba` color](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color).

> The RGB color model is extended in this specification to include
>   “alpha” to allow specification of the opacity of a color.

For example,

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #ff0, #0ff);
}
p {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3); /* semi-transparent solid blue */
  padding: 70px;
}
```

```html
<p>Semi-transparent background but fully opaque text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Opacity to a parent container will also apply to the children. If you want to have a background with an opacity effect you could use RGBA for the background color. This applies to solid colors and there is an option for working with gradients as well.

If you have an image you want to use, you could position absolute the image behind your content using a div/container. Give that container an opacity and a position.